# What does "doom loop" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Is it the same as "endless loop"?

> The Flywheel and the Doom Loop. Those who launch revolutions, dra- matic change programs, and wrenching restructurings will almost cer- tainly fail to make the leap from good to great. No matter how dramatic the end result, the good-to-great transformations never happened in one fell swoop. There was no single defining action, no grand program, no one killer innovation, no solitary lucky break, no miracle moment. C K' L Rather, the process resembled relentlessly pushing a giant heavy flywheel in one direction, turn upon turn, building momentum until a point of breakthrough, and beyond.

Source: https://www.coursehero.com/file/p4m0kaq/The-Flywheel-and-the-Doom-Loop-Those-who-launch-revolutions-dra-matic-change/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **doom loop** is a situation, usually for a business or similar organisation, where there is a feedback loop which means each action makes the situation worse.  The term was popularised in the 2001 management book *Good to Great* [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_to_Great).

> ... we were in the Doom Loop -- the downward spiral described by *Good to Great* author Jim Collins that is characterized by a parade of leaders, shifting strategies, and consistently poorer results. [Fast Company](https://www.fastcompany.com/49293/lessons-doom-loop)

Other writers use the term **vicious circle** [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtuous_circle_and_vicious_circle) which is much older: OED gives earliest reference as 1792.